# SDRAM bidirectionality - do reads & writes count the same in 'official' bandwidth figures?

Tags: database, memory, bandwidth, memory-bandwidth

Is SDRAM capable of loading and storing simultaneously?

If so, how does storing and loading simultaneously effect bandwidth?

- Does the overall bandwidth, as the sum of the store and load bandwidth, drop when doing both?
- Is it the same overall sum but divided between loading and storing?
- Or can I use the entire stated bandwidth for storing *and* the entire stated bandwidth for storing??

Answer (score 0):

One of the main advantages of SDRAM with respect to asynchronous DRAM is in fact the support for multiple internal banks inside the DRAM chip. Memory access commands to different internal banks can be served by the SDRAM controller simultaneously. Such simultaneous access commands can be either load or store as long as they target different banks. 
Modern SDRAM devices are divided into either 2, 4 or 8 (from DDR2) independent internal data banks. Bank selection is done by reserving 1, 2 or 3 bits of the requested address.

In addition to that SDRAM allows some sort of pipelining. That is, new commands can be processed while still waiting for the result of the previous one.

Finally, remind that on modern SDRAMs the minimum read/write unit has been notably increased. While standard SDRAM used to read/write only 1 word, with DDR2 SDRAM you read/write 4 consecutive words with a single command. With DDR3 this minimum unit becomes 8 consecutive words. This feature can further speed up memory operations by reducing the number of accesses to the SDRAM banks.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, everything you've written is completely independent of whether you're storing or loading and these operations are all the same to the SDRAM chips. Right?

Comment: If you are asking me about the timing behaviour I would not say that load and store are the same from the SDRAM chips perspective. This depends a lot on both the SDRAM type and the SDRAM controller. What I say is that, from a bank perspective you can issue commands in parallel, irrespective of their type.

Comment: For instance I have seen memory controllers (AURIX TriCore) that implement a read buffer for each core used to cache the last accessed words. Such read buffers speed up reads of sequential words but do not help with writes. Other memory controllers do some sort of re-ordering of loads and stores and might end up delaying stores (if directed to different addresses) to execute more contiguous loads in a row and benefit from spatial locality.

Comment: ... but is this kind of read caching relied upon by the published timing figures, or is it just a "cherry on top of the cream" so to speak?

Comment: Published timing figures most likely describe commands on the banks, costs of row selection, prefetching and so on. So as you said this read caching is the "cherry on top of the cream" :)